# Where to modify font size for find dialog?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2020.3.1 when making search font size is too small in : https://prnt.sc/104tjoe

Where can I modify under “Settings” ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find in Files` doesn't have designated font settings and uses the UI font instead.

You can configure it at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Use custom font`.